# Get value from JSON object having multiple keys

Tags: json, parsing, gson, jsonparser

I am having a JSON Object as below:

```
{
    "winame": "123",
    "val": "[
        {
            "gurName": "sds",
            "gurType": "",
            "crNo": "",
            "crissueDate": "",
            "dob": "",
            "gender": "",
            "address": "",
            "maritialStatus": "",
            "cache": ""
        }
    ]"
}
```

In which first key is value and second key contains the values of some Java Object type. How to parse the value of 'winame' and 'val' into that java Object.

Comment: What does VO stand for?

Comment: It is java object. I edited...

Comment: Are double quotes in val actually escaped like `\"gurName\": \"sds\"`? And can you show the result class you want to parse to?

Answer (score 1):

You can parse JSON with any number of keys.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("xyz");
String winame= obj.getJSONObject("winame");

JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("val");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
{
    String gurName = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("gurName");
    String gurType = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("gurType");
    String crNo = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("crNo");
    String crissueDate = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("crissueDate");
    String dob = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("dob");
    String gender = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("gender");
    String address = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("address");
    String maritialStatus = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("maritialStatus");
    String cache = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("cache");    
}
```